# Questions about various buttons on android

Tags: java, android, button, android-button

I'm developing an application where it will contain several buttons.

I need your help to see if I can improve the code.

The actions do the same thing just change the background color and pass me what the value of the button.

The application has several other screens that have many buttons with almost the same actions, only with some changes in the return.

[(Image) I'm using linear layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s7ur.png)

My code:

```
 btnBall01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    count1++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall01.getId());
                    btnBall01.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall01.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityMegasenaCreateGame.this, "Verde " + games.getActualNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (count1 != 1){
                        count1 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall01.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                         Toast.makeText(ActivityMegasenaCreateGame.this, "Branco " + games.getActualNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall02.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    btnBall02.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count2++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall02.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall02.getText().toString());

                    if (count2 != 1){
                        count2 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall02.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall03.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall03.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count3++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall03.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall03.getText().toString());

                    if (count3 !=1){
                        count3 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall03.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall04.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall04.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count4++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall04.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall04.getText().toString());

                    if (count4 != 1){
                        count4 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall04.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }

                }
            });

            btnBall05.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall05.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count5++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall05.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall05.getText().toString());

                    if (count5 != 1){
                        count5 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall05.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall06.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall06.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count6++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall06.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall06.getText().toString());

                    if (count6 != 1){
                        count6 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall06.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall07.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall07.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count7++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall07.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall07.getText().toString());

                    if (count7 != 1){
                        count7 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall07.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall08.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall08.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count8++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall08.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall08.getText().toString());

                    if (count8 != 1){
                        count8 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall08.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall09.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall09.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count9++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall09.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall09.getText().toString());

                    if (count9 != 1){
                        count9 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall09.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall10.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count10++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall10.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall10.getText().toString());

                    if (count10 != 1){
                        count10 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall10.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall11.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count11++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall11.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall11.getText().toString());

                    if (count11 != 1){
                        count11 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall11.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall12.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count12++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall12.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall12.getText().toString());

                    if(count12 != 1){
                        count12 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall12.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall13.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count13++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall13.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall13.getText().toString());

                    if(count13 != 1){
                        count13 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall13.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall14.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count14++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall14.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall14.getText().toString());

                    if (count14 != 1){
                        count14 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall14.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });

            btnBall15.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnBall15.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
                    count15++;
                    selectedNumber++;
                    games.setBallId(btnBall15.getId());
                    games.setActualNumber(btnBall15.getText().toString());

                    if (count15 != 1){
                        count15 = 0;
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber -2;
                        btnBall15.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
                        initializeComponentsBallsButtons();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Are you adding this buttons in a linear layout? Please share your layout. I'm pretty sure you can add all these buttons in a loop

Comment: I'm using linear layout

Comment: I added an image

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement this way

```
//Generate buttons
for (int i = 0; i <= buttonCount; ++i) {
    Button btn = new Button(context);
    btn.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    btn.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
    linearLayout.addView(btn);
}

//OnClickListener
 OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        Button btn = (Button) view;
        String str = btn.getText().toString();
        int index = Integer.parseInt(str); /*<-- create a method using this index*/          
    }
};
```

Now you know which button has been clicked. Do your calculations according to your button index.

**N.B:**  This is not the full code what you need, just the base logic of implementation.

Comment: If parsing the text and getting the id doesn't work for you, then you can create a custom button extending `Button` class and add an index field in that.